# create multiple lists for a given test data in python

Tags: list, python-2.7

I am relatively new to python so please excuse me if this is a very rudimentary question. This is my first time asking question.
I have a test file which is of the format below.

```
1 2 4
1 3 2
1 4 1
2 1 2
2 2 1
2 3 1
3 2 3
3 7 1
4 1 1
....
```

I am trying to read the file line by line and for each value in column 1 (1, 2, 3...), i need to create a list of the form below

```
list_1 = [[2,4], [3,2], [4,1]]
list_2 = [[1,2], [2,1], [3,1]]
list_3 = [[2,3], [7,1]]
list_4 = [[1,1]]
...
list_n
```

where values in the list are from column 2 and column 3 respectively.
Sincerely appreciate any guidance in this regard. Thank you

Comment: Why can't that be a dictionary?

Comment: it can be, I was thinking more lists but which would be preferable? dict or lists

Comment: For your case, you can have a dictionary of lists, and you can access individual lists with `dict["list_1"]`

Answer (score 1):

Use a defaultdict. This way, you don't have to check if your key already exists in the dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict


def parse(filename):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            c1, c2, c3 = map(int, line.split())
            result[c1].append([c2, c3])

    return result


def main():
    result = parse("test_data.txt")
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```